# XML Tags using Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I am currently building an XML export for a Real Estate app. using the Builder gem in Rails. And I am looking for a way to do the following:

```
<commercialRent>
  "commercialRent figure"
  <range>
    ...
  </range>
</commercialRent>
```

I can't seem to find a way to implement the "Text Goes Here" part

My code:

```
b.commercialRent(period: "annual", plusOutgoings: self.plus_outgoings) {  
      self.rent_price;
        b.range { 
          b.min(self.rent_psm_pa_min); 
          b.max(self.rent_psm_pa_max)
      };
    };
```

Returns:

```
<commercialRent period="annual" plusOutgoings="no">
  <rentPerSquareMeter>
    <range>
      <min>1000</min>
      <max>10000</max>
    </range>
  </rentPerSquareMeter>
</commercialRent>
```

Everything prints fine, except the self.rent_price is missing.
I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [`text!` method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jimweirich/builder/Builder/XmlBase#text!-instance_method) to produce a text node:

> **- (Object) text!(text)**
>
> Append text to the output target. Escape any markup. May be used within the markup brackets as:
>
> ```
> builder.p { |b| b.br; b.text! "HI" }   #=>  <p><br/>HI</p>
> ```

So something like this should do the trick:

```
b.commercialRent(period: "annual", plusOutgoings: self.plus_outgoings) do
  b.text! self.rent_price
  #...
end
```